# Ruby array adapter

Tags: ruby, performance, adapter

I must query a set of model objects from different sources. Each source returns an Array with Hash like objects, but the layout of the same model (**LogDoc**) is not the same.

My first approach was wrapping the query result objects into an array adapter that basically transforms each element extracted within an **#each** block. This is what I came up:

```
class MongoQueryAdapter
  extend Forwardable

  def initialize(mongo_query)
    @query_rows = mongo_query
    ...
  end

  def_delegators :@query_rows, ...

  def each(&block)
    @query_rows.each do |raw|
      log = LogDoc.new raw
      block.call(log)
    end
  end
end
```

This is the pattern I believe is more appropriate for my use case, but I am concerned about the performance since I heard that **block.call** is inefficient compared to **yield**.

Is it possible to implement this using **yield**?  Or is the performance impact really worth considering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just `yield` instead of calling the block, no other change should be required.

```
def each
  if block_given?
    @query_rows.each do |raw|
      yield LogDoc.new(raw)
    end
  else
    # return Enumerator or raise
  end
end
```

Looking at the code, I think you can actually simplify this a bit:

```
def each(&block)
  @query_rows.map { |raw| LogDoc.new(raw) }.each(&block)
end
```

And yes, `yield` tends to be much faster:

```
Calculating -------------------------------------
        bench_block    30.600k i/100ms
        bench_yield    42.073k i/100ms
-------------------------------------------------
        bench_block    768.311k (± 6.0%) i/s -      3.825M
        bench_yield      3.917M (± 2.8%) i/s -     19.564M
```

Comment: could you post a gist on how you did the benchmarking?

Comment: @SystematicFrank See https://gist.github.com/jiripospisil/0774b7767d252d871992 . You will probably get much higher numbers as I'm running this on a fairly old laptop.

Comment: Thanks! Good profiling skills is a goldmine that tends to be greatly underestimated

Comment: Looks like a more generic adapter will have to make a Proc.call https://gist.github.com/fgarcia/189e2dc221fc51084780 Would you agree?

Comment: @SystematicFrank Yeah, `yield` cannot distinguish between blocks. If you're fine with transforming the raw values immediately however (not only after the call to `each`), you can map over the values in the constructor (and store the values transformed). That would allow you to use `yield` in both cases.